# How can I stop text block Wrapping When this line is full?

Tags: wpf, textblock

[image]

In my wpf application, I have added a text block control and set its value with Chinese and English text. But it wraps and I don't want it to wrap.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add "TextBlock.TextAlignment Property" Like

```
<TextBlock Name="tbllist" Text="Your text" TextWrapping="Wrap"      TextAlignment="Justify"/>
```

Comment: Thank you ! But add TextAlignment  can't resolve this problem.In my opinion i would reWrite TextBlock Template.It'is only way.